# Where to go after taking beginner HTML, CSS, and JavaScript courses

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been in the process of making a career change towards front-end development. I've taken several beginning HTML, CSS, and JavaScript courses but am feeling stuck.

I'm not sure where to take all these skills and apply them. I've thought of creating an app for practice, but don't understand the back-end of things. Does anyone have any recommendations for someone who has taken front end dev courses and is looking to advance to the next level (where ever that may be)?

Hopefully this makes sense and others have been or are in a similar circumstance. Thanks!

Amit

Comment: The most effective way to improve on your skills is to keep building. If you do not want to learn back end stuff then make static web pages, which could then be enhanced with some javascript. I think it would be a good idea to learn some server side programming and databases, even if you do not intend to do that side of it all it will help you understand how websites work

Answer (score 4):

I would say a great way to learn new stuff is to watch video courses. I've learned a lot from sites like http://www.lynda.com/ and http://tutsplus.com/ since there are courses for everyone - beginners to experts.

I would say, try to get the basics about a CMS like Wordpress, and start developing themes to try out your front-end skills.

If you are interested in some PHP development, I'd recommend to read about it and try out some PHP frameworks that will get you started.

Comment: Ok great, thanks a lot! I'll definitely check those sites out.